# VS2015 NTFS Long filename restriction

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ntfs

There is a limitation of 259 symbols for a file name in NTFS.
When I start downloading a project f rom TFS, I receive the following error

[image]

It pretty much says that the file length is more than the allowed sixe of 259 symbols.

However, with Windows Anniversary update, we can disable this restriction with group policy option **LongPathsEnabled**

(check out my other [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1119883/windows-10-enable-ntfs-long-paths-policy-option-missing), which shows how enable this setting)

The problem is that I cannot get Visual Studio to work with files which are longer than 259 symbols.
Did anyone managed to find a workaround ?

Comment: According to https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2156195-fix-260-character-file-name-length-limitation the issue has been fixed in .NET 4.6.2 and the fix should be avaiable with the next version visual studio and TFS. You can try the preview of visual studio 15 to check if works.

Comment: I am using the latest version of VS 2015 Update 3. The issue should not be TFS related.

Comment: Visual studio 15 is not visual studio 2015 (version 14)

Comment: Aaah, I see what you mean. I will try with https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs15-relnotes